# unas de las funciones de mi contrato solidity no responde

Tags: solidity

cuando realize pruebas desplegaba los contratos en polygon mumbai y todo respondia bien, lo desplegaba mediante truffle, pero al pasar a la red de real de polygon que fue desplegado por remix una de las funciones no responde al llamado. la version que se uso en truffle fue la 0.8.19 la que remix uso fue la 0.8.25 ¿tiene esto algo que ver con que la funcion no responda?

la solucion que probe fue desplegar el contrato por remix en la red de prueba polygon mumbai y funciono normal

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.